# Hover > :before > Hover ? How?

Tags: css, less, pseudo-element

I am writing a mixin in Less that adds a play button to video tags. It looks like this:

```
.playVideoButton(@size: 64px) {
  &:before {
    content: "";
    width: @size;
    height: @size;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    .transform(translate(-50%, -50%));
    .border-radius(50%);
    border: 2px solid #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  }
  &:after {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    content: "";
    border-top: @size / 4 solid transparent;
    border-bottom: @size / 4 solid transparent;
    border-left: @size / 2.4 solid #fff;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    .transform(translate(-35%, -50%));
  }
  &:hover {
    &:before {
      display: block;
      &:hover {
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);
      }
    }
    &:after {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
```

It Works fine but I want to make a second hover effect for the `:before`. So I write at the end: `&:hover > &:before > &:hover {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.60);}` but when I hover the `:before` element I don't get a change of the background opacity.

Chromes Dev Tool hides the hover settings for pseudo elements. So is it not possible to modify them without JavaScript?

Comment: At first glance (if I'm not mistaken) when you hover over a `before` element, the main element is not counted as hovered anymore (i.e. things like `*:hover:before:hover` do not make much sense since this is an impossible state). Yet again at first glance I'd put those style into `before:hover`.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: No buddy, hovering on a child almost always triggers the hover on the parent also. In this case, it doesn't work because you can't attach pseudo-classes to a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At present you can't attach `:hover` (or any other pseudo-classes to a pseudo-element). It is implied by the below text in the [W3C Spec for pseudo-elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements):

> Only one pseudo-element may appear per selector, and if present it ***must appear after the sequence of simple selectors*** that represents the subjects of the selector.

and the following one from the [W3C Spec for selector syntax](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax):

> One pseudo-element may be ***appended to the last sequence of simple selectors*** in a selector.

Pseudo-classes (like `:hover`, `:link` etc) are simple selectors and a pseudo-element can only be appended after all such simple selectors. So, it rules out the possibility of a `div:hover:before:hover` or `div:before:hover`.

---

In the below snippet, a very simple one, you can see how the `div:after:hover` selector never gets matched while the `div:hover:after` does.

```css
div:after {
  display: block;
  content: 'World';
  background: beige;
}
div:after:hover {
  background: green;
}
div:hover:after {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
div:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>Hello!</div>
```

You should consider creating that ***play button using an actual child element*** (instead of a pseudo) and then attach the `:hover` selector to it.

Comment: Hmmm i see... Okay then i accept this fact and thank you all for your time! It just would be cool when the button get a darker background when i hover it. but then i have to add a html element.

Comment: @SvenBudak: You're welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if it helped (click the hollow tick mark below voting button).